# prove that $S_n < l <T_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I have $$S_n =\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$$ 
and $$T_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} + \frac{1}{n!}$$
I found that Sn is increasing and Tn is decreasing
but I have a hard time saying what are the limits of Sn and Tn and the exercise is telling me they both have the same limit $(l)$ and I have to prove that $S_n \le l\le T_n$
thanks for the help

Comment: Well, it should be fairly obvious that the limits are $e$, right?

Comment: Well, we have the [incomplete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html), $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{\Gamma(n,x)}{(n-1)!}e^x$$as well as the [exponential sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFunction.html).

Comment: ok thank you i'll look into it